# How can I deal with ports that are open on the WAN side of the router?

Tags: networking, router, security, home-networking, port

Some ports in the WAN side of the router seem to be open

- The port scan in the ShieldsUp! site showed ports 22, 23, 80, 443 and 8000 as open
- Then, by checking with nmap while connected to a mobile network I got:

  ```
   PORT     STATE SERVICE
   22/tcp   open  ssh
   23/tcp   open  telnet
   80/tcp   open  http
   443/tcp  open  https
   8000/tcp open  http-alt
  ```

These ports appeared as *filtered* and *stealth* before a router reset. The router (a gateway) I have is Askey RTF8115VW, which I got from my ISP. There is barely any information about it.

There is no option to configure this from the web management interface. It has been suggested to me that I try and configure it through telnet, but upon trying to login into it I get the message
`connection closed by foreign host`

In what way can I stop having them open from the internet?

Comment: Your question is entirely dependent on the make and model of your router, and how to configure it might also depend on if your ISP has asked to have it "locked" - to a specific setup. You might also have luck in finding a settings file to apply, e.g. available on your ISP's (support) webpage.

Comment: does the management interface let you make firewall rules more or less arbitrarily? it sounds like your software is already honoring some form of zone-checking, but if you put firewall rules on those ports,  blocking access from the WAN interface, that would probably give you the sense of security you are looking for. or better yet, add a router of your own behind the ISP router.  Then you don;t need to trust their configuration nearly so much.

Comment: Do you know what is running on those open wan ports? have you attempted trying http://yourwanip/ ? To me it looks like an application or device wanted those ports open thanks to uPnP. In your router configuration look for uPnP and switch it off, then reboot the router, and run the portscan again.

Comment: Link doesn't work, I couldn't find anything about yourwanip. I guess the -A parameter in nmap would serve for this, right? Upon restarting the router one of the first things I did was disable UPnP, so it is not on.